# How to cancel btrfs defragmentation

Tags: btrfs, defragmentation

How can I cancel a btrfs defragmentation? With `btrfs fi balance /` you can use `btrfs balance cancel /`. I can find no option for defragmentation. How can I safely cancel?

Comment: simply press ctrl+c.